# Pandas: Combine resampling with groupby and calculate time differences

Tags: group-by, pandas, time-series

I am doing data analysis with trading data. I would like to use Pandas in order to examine the times when the traders are active.

In particular, I try to extract the difference in minutes between the dates of every first trade of every trader for each day and cumulate it to a monthly basis

The data looks like this:

```
Timestamp (Datetime)  | Buyer | Volume 
--------------------------------------
2012-01-01 09:00:00   | John  | 10
2012-01-01 10:00:00   | Mark  | 10
2012-01-01 16:00:00   | Mark  | 10
2012-01-01 11:00:00   | Kevin | 10
2012-02-01 10:00:00   | Mark  | 10
2012-02-01 09:00:00   | John  | 10
2012-02-01 17:00:00   | Mark  | 10
```

Right now I use resampling to retrieve the first trade on a daily basis. However, I want to group also by the buyer to calculate the differences in their trading dates. Like this

```
Timestamp (Datetime)  | Buyer | Volume 
--------------------------------------
2012-01-01 09:00:00   | John  | 10
2012-01-01 10:00:00   | Mark  | 10
2012-01-01 11:00:00   | Kevin | 10
2012-01-02 10:00:00   | Mark  | 10
2012-01-02 09:00:00   | John  | 10
```

Overall I am looking to calculate the differences in minutes between the first trades on a daily basis for each trader.

**Update**

For example in the case of John on the 2012-01-01: Dist = 60 (Diff John-Mark) + 120 (Diff John-Kevin) = 180

I would highly appreciate if anyone has an idea how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: can you add some expected output? (e.g. create it manually for your example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original frame (the resampled one)

```
In [71]: df_orig
Out[71]: 
   buyer                date  volume
0   John 2012-01-01 09:00:00      10
1   Mark 2012-01-01 10:00:00      10
2  Kevin 2012-01-01 11:00:00      10
3   Mark 2012-01-02 10:00:00      10
4   John 2012-01-02 09:00:00      10
```

Set the index to the date column, keeping the date column in place

```
In [75]: df = df_orig.set_index('date',drop=False)
```

Create this aggregation function

```
def f(frame):
    frame.sort('date',inplace=True)
    frame['start'] = frame.date.iloc[0]
    return frame
```

Groupby the single date

```
In [74]: x = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1d')).apply(f)
```

Create the differential in minutes

```
In [86]: x['diff'] = (x.date-x.start).apply(lambda x: float(x.item().total_seconds())/60)

In [87]: x
Out[87]: 
                                buyer                date  volume               start  diff
           date                                                                            
2012-01-01 2012-01-01 09:00:00   John 2012-01-01 09:00:00      10 2012-01-01 09:00:00     0
           2012-01-01 10:00:00   Mark 2012-01-01 10:00:00      10 2012-01-01 09:00:00    60
           2012-01-01 11:00:00  Kevin 2012-01-01 11:00:00      10 2012-01-01 09:00:00   120
2012-01-02 2012-01-02 09:00:00   John 2012-01-02 09:00:00      10 2012-01-02 09:00:00     0
           2012-01-02 10:00:00   Mark 2012-01-02 10:00:00      10 2012-01-02 09:00:00    60
```

Here's the explanation. We use the TimeGrouper to have the grouping by date, where a frame is passed to the function f. This function, then uses the first date of the day (the sort is necessary here). You subtract this from the date on the entry to get a timedelta64, which is then massaged to minutes (this is a bit hacky right now because of some numpy issues, should be more natural in 0.12)

Thanks for you update, I originally thought you wanted the diff per buyer, not from the first buyer, but that's just a minor tweak.

Update:

To track the buyer name as well (which corresponds to the start date), just include
it in the function f

```
def f(frame):
    frame.sort('date',inplace=True)
    frame['start'] = frame.date.iloc[0]
    frame['start_buyer'] = frame.buyer.iloc[0]
    return frame
```

Then can groupby on this at the end:

```
In [14]: x.groupby(['start_buyer']).sum()
Out[14]: 
             diff
start_buyer      
John          240
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. However, you were right I am also trying to calculate the diff per buyer (which would be for Kevin: 120 (John-Kevin) + 60 (Mark-John) = 180) and finally aggregated those daily sums to a monthly granularity (which would be for John 180 (2012-01-01) + 60 (2012-01-02) = 240). How would you do this?

Comment: I added an update, which I think does what you want. Furthermore, you may need to put a Timegrouper on a monthly basis on the whole thing to aggregate per month, but should be a simple extension